# How can I get past Chapter 3 - Lesson 4: Air Chains?

Tags: skullgirls

Embarrassingly enough, I'm rather stuck in the tutorial in *Skullgirls* (Steam release). I'm having trouble in Chapter 3 - Lesson 4: Air Chains, specifically the last section, Putting It All Together III.

This video shows someone pulling the launcher off successfully, but he does it really quickly and it doesn't really help me with figuring out the timing on my own.

I can get through the first 8 moves fine, but I'm having a lot of trouble consistently going from the jumping Medium Kick to the airborne Hairball. After that, I need to cancel the Hairball into Gregor Samson. I'm fairly bad at canceling moves in general, so having to do it in the air is really difficult for me.

While I was able to get through the earlier part of the lesson, I just can't seem to pull this off. Once I complete the mid-air kicks, I find it hard to consistently do a regular Hairball move, let alone cancel it into a Gregor Samson. I figured out that I'm apparently just not doing the Hairball fast enough after the kicks to have it count as one combo, but I'm having trouble making that transition smoothly.

Cancelling a Hairball on the ground is difficult for me, as I haven't really gotten a feel for the timing, so trying to do it mid-air is even harder. How soon do I need to cancel after I do the attack?

What can I do to improve my chances at actually pulling this off?

Answer (score 1):

First off, let's verify what does 'cancelling' mean:

> **Canceling** - The act of interrupting the animation of one attack and transitioning in to another

Basically, it means from one move, you can cancel it early to combo into another move.

Now, you need to make sure the j.MK (Bounce and Volume) only hit once for you to be able to cancel into a Hairball. j.MK pushes you back making it harder for you to land a Hairball.So what you can do is j.MK (one hit) -> Hairball.

As for Gregor Samson you also need to make sure Hairball doesn't end it's move. After experimenting for a while, you can cancel Hairball into Gregor Samson at any given time during Hairball. Although, you need to input the Gregor Samson really quick to make sure you can cancel Hairball. Spam it if you have to.

In short just try j.MK (one hit) -> Hairball ->(at any moment and quickly) Gregor Samson.

If you need visual representation:

- **[j.MK -> Hairball](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHL9L.jpg)**
- **[Hairball -> Gregor Samson](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtMBn.jpg)**

It's gonna take a while before it loads